# Update button wont populate in datagridview

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I got this update button but won't update the changes that i've made. First of all, I got this datagridview that has update and delete button. If I click any of the information in the row and hit the update button it will send the data to my new form which is the UpdateRecords form. And below is the code

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     UpdateRecords obj = new UpdateRecords();
     obj.textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
     obj.textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
     obj.textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
     obj.textBox4.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
     obj.comboBox1.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
     obj.textBox6.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
     obj.textBox7.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
     obj.comboBox2.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
     obj.textBox9.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
     obj.comboBox3.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[10].Value.ToString();
     obj.ShowDialog();
}
```

All the information in that particular row will be sent to the update records form then I will try to update the information but its always says Successful but it won't update in my database and in my Records form. This is the code of the UpdateRecords upon saving the new information will be changed

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-EB4EK81\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=TACLC; Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd;

    cmd = new SqlCommand("update tbl_registerStudent set rfidno = @rfidno, lastname = @lastname, firstname = @firstname, middlename = @middlename, gender = @gender, address = @address, contactno = @contactno, gradelevel = @gradelevel, year = @year, section = @section where rfidno=@rfidno", con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rfidno", textBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", textBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", textBox3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middlename", textBox4.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", comboBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", textBox6.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactno", textBox7.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gradelevel", comboBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", textBox9.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@section", comboBox3.Text);
    MessageBox.Show("Update Successfully", "Update Message Prompt", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);


    Records objs = new Records();
    if (objs == null)
    {
        objs.Parent = this;
    }
    objs.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Sorry. Im new and still learning about programming.

Comment: You are missing cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Hi @ziakhan. Oh I see! Now its working! Thank you so much